# AWK How to modify this code so it prints num instances instead of 0 and 1

Tags: linux, awk

I have a bash script with some AWK in it for a problem I'm trying to solve.

```
<targets.txt xargs -n1 -P4 bash -c "
awk 'NR==FNR{a[\$0];next} 
{
  if (\$0 in a) 
  {
    printf \"1,\"
  } 
  else 
  {
    printf \"0,\"
  }
}' \"\$1\" values.txt | sed $'s\x01$\x01'\"\$(<<<\"\$1\" cut -d/ -f3)\"'\n'$'\x01'
```

It prints "`1,`" if there's an occurrence of $0 in `a`, otherwise it prints "`0,`". However, instead of printing 1 if there's an occurrence I'd like it to instead print the number of occurrences.

Is there a way to do this?

Example targets.txt

```
./dataset/tallperson/file1.txt
./dataset/tallperson/file2.txt
./dataset/tallperson/file3.txt
./dataset/shortperson/file4.txt
```

Example ./dataset/tallperson/file1.txt

```
LOL
Lol
Hel
lo.
```

Example ./dataset/tallperson/file2.txt

```
LOL
LOL
Wei
rd.
```

Example ./dataset/tallperson/file3.txt

```
Lol
Lol
```

Example ./dataset/shortperson/file4.txt

```
hah
a t
hat
was
fun
ny.
LOL
LOL
```

Example values.txt

```
LOL
Lol
Hel
lo.
Wei
rd.
hah
a t
hat
was
fun
ny.
```

Desired Output

```
1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,tallperson
2,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,tallperson
0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,tallperson
2,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,shortperson
```

Undesired Output (From my script)

```
1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,tallperson
1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,tallperson
0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,tallperson
1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,shortperson
```

I have values.txt which contains a list of unique 3-character values from every file in targets.txt. No file.txt contains a value which isn't in targets.txt. I just wanted to look at every file in targets.txt, and count how many of each value the file contains from values.txt.

Comment: Add targets.txt and your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need anything other than awk to do this, e.g. with GNU awk for gensub(), ARGIND and ENDFILE:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="," }
ARGIND == 1 {
    ARGV[ARGC] = $0
    ARGC++
    next
}
ARGIND == 2 {
    strings[++numStrings] = $0
    next
}
{ cnt[$0]++ }
ENDFILE {
    if ( ARGIND > 2 ) {
        for (stringNr=1; stringNr<=numStrings; stringNr++) {
            string = strings[stringNr]
            printf "%d%s", cnt[string], OFS
        }
        print gensub(/(.*\/)?([^/]+)\/[^/]+$/,"\\2",1,FILENAME)
        delete cnt
    }
}
$ awk -f tst.awk targets.txt values.txt
1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,tallperson
2,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,tallperson
0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,tallperson
2,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,shortperson
```

You don't actually need the "values.txt" file of course unless you really do require a specific order of the output fields that can't be determined from the input:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="," }
ARGIND == 1 {
    ARGV[ARGC] = $0
    ARGC++
    next
}
{
    if ( !seen[$0]++ ) {
        strings[++numStrings] = $0
    }
    cnt[ARGIND,$0]++
}
END {
    for (stringNr=1; stringNr<=numStrings; stringNr++) {
        string = strings[stringNr]
        printf "%s%s", string, OFS
    }
    print "directory"

    for (fileNr=2; fileNr<=ARGIND; fileNr++) {
        for (stringNr=1; stringNr<=numStrings; stringNr++) {
            string = strings[stringNr]
            printf "%d%s", cnt[fileNr,string], OFS
        }
        print gensub(/(.*\/)?([^/]+)\/[^/]+$/,"\\2",1,ARGV[fileNr])
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk targets.txt
LOL,Lol,Hel,lo.,Wei,rd.,hah,a t,hat,was,fun,ny.,directory
1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,tallperson
2,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,tallperson
0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,tallperson
2,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,shortperson
```

I added a header to that 2nd script - if you don't want it then don't add it.

If you REALLY don't care about output order then all you need is:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="," }
ARGIND == 1 {
    ARGV[ARGC] = $0
    ARGC++
    next
}
{
    strings[$0]
    cnt[ARGIND,$0]++
}
END {
    for (string in strings) {
        printf "%s%s", string, OFS
    }
    print "directory"

    for (fileNr=2; fileNr<=ARGIND; fileNr++) {
        for (string in strings) {
            printf "%d%s", cnt[fileNr,string], OFS
        }
        print gensub(/(.*\/)?([^/]+)\/[^/]+$/,"\\2",1,ARGV[fileNr])
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk targets.txt
was,rd.,Lol,ny.,LOL,Wei,hat,hah,lo.,fun,a t,Hel,directory
0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,tallperson
0,1,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,tallperson
0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,tallperson
1,0,0,1,2,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,shortperson
```

Comment: I'm getting a bunch of errors on the line with "print gensub(/(.*\/)?([^/]+)\/[^/]+$/,"\\2",1,ARGV[fileNr])

awk: tst.awk: line 20: regular expression compile failed (bad class -- [], [^] or [)
(.*/)?([^
awk: tst.awk: line 20: syntax error at or near ]
awk: tst.awk: line 20: regular expression compile failed (bad class -- [], [^] or [)
[^
awk: tst.awk: line 20: runaway regular expression /,"\\2",1,F ...

Comment: What goes `awk --version` tell you about the version of gawk you're running? I suspect you're not actually running gawk (maybe it's mawk?) but in any case you could try adding a ```\``` before each of the `/`s inside the bracket expressions to see if that helps. Or just get the directory name some other way, eg. `n=split(FILENAME,p,"/"); print p[n-1]`.

Comment: Yes. I am running Mawk. Not gawk.

Comment: OK, then run gawk as I mentioned is required in my answer. You tagged your question linux and AFAIK gawk is the default awk on Linux.